# azure piplines Unable to create directory "/home/iradmin/aaaa/my-proj/WebUI/". Access to the path is denied

Tags: linux, .net-core, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

azure pipline yaml publish config

---

trigger:

- testing

pool:
vmImage: ubuntu-latest

variables:
buildConfiguration: 'Release'
PublishPath: '/home/iradmin/aaaa/my-proj'

```
- task: UseDotNet@2 
  displayName: "Building .NET Core 5.x sdk"
  inputs:
    version: '5.0.x'
    packageType: sdk


- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet restore'
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    projects: '**/*.csproj'
    feedsToUse: 'select'

- script: dotnet build --configuration $(buildConfiguration)
  displayName: 'Building'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: "Publish"
  inputs:
    command: 'publish'
    publishWebProjects: false
    projects: '**/**/WebUI.csproj'
    arguments: '-r linux-x64 --configuration $(BuildConfiguration) --output $(PublishPath)'
    modifyOutputPath: false
    zipAfterPublish: false
```

---

all goes well but ...
output error in publish step

---

2021-07-31T13:48:01.0670834Z /opt/hostedtoolcache/dotnet/sdk/5.0.302/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Publish.targets(111,5): error MSB3191: Unable to create directory "/home/iradmin/aaaa/my-proj/WebUI/". Access to the path '/home/iradmin/aaaa/my-proj/WebUI/' is denied. [/home/vsts/work/1/s/src/WebUI/WebUI.csproj]
2021-07-31T13:48:01.0704470Z ##[error]Error: The process '/opt/hostedtoolcache/dotnet/dotnet' failed with exit code 1
2021-07-31T13:48:01.0716597Z ##[warning].NET 5 has some compatibility issues with older Nuget versions(<=5.7), so if you are using an older Nuget version(and not dotnet cli) to restore, then the dotnet cli commands (e.g. dotnet build) which rely on such restored packages might fail. To mitigate such error, you can either: (1) - Use dotnet cli to restore, (2) - Use Nuget version 5.8 to restore, (3) - Use global.json using an older sdk version(<=3) to build
2021-07-31T13:48:01.0720360Z Info: Azure Pipelines hosted agents have been updated and now contain .Net 5.x SDK/Runtime along with the older .Net Core version which are currently lts. Unless you have locked down a SDK version for your project(s), 5.x SDK might be picked up which might have breaking behavior as compared to previous versions. You can learn more about the breaking changes here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/ and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/ . To learn about more such changes and troubleshoot, refer here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/dotnet-core-cli?view=azure-devops#troubleshooting
2021-07-31T13:48:01.0723236Z ##[error]Dotnet command failed with non-zero exit code on the following projects : /home/vsts/work/1/s/src/WebUI/WebUI.csproj
2021-07-31T13:48:01.0727745Z ##[section]Finishing: Publish

---

thanks in advance

Comment: Please take the time to ensure that your code and error messages are formatted in a readable way.

Answer (score 0):

The `/home/iradmin/...` output directory is probably not existing, or you do not have the rights to write onto it. In both cases, it's best to create new files and directories where you know you have proper access rights. On Azure DevOps agents this directory is certainly the one specified by the predefined
variable [`Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#build-variables-devops-services).

You can take a look to the `https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/dotnet-core-cli?view=azure-devops#publish-projects-to-specified-folder`, where the `arguments` are defined as follows:

```yaml
 arguments: '-o $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/Output'
```

I'd suggest to rethink the `PublishPath` variable definition, and set its value to for example: `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/Output`